# Desire2Learn - Creating a new user with password

Tags: desire2learn

I'm using the Valence Desire2Learn API to enrol users in a client's LMS, and am having a problem with creating new users.

There is no "Password" property on the CreateUserData object the API is expecting me to pass in for a new user. I assume this is generated automatically ... however the autogenerated welcome email that gets sent out contains "{Password}" as the password (and this doesn't actually work when attempting to login so I assume it means the password is null).

I know I can set the password manually after the user is created, but the welcome email is already sent at that stage so it's not really useful ... I know I can suppress this email and generate one myself but it feels unnecessary given the fact that the autogenerated email option is there in the first place ...

Anyone have any suggestion as to how I can avoid this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Just noticed that the password was null in the auto generated email in your description of the problem. I will try this out on my instance and let you know how it works for me.

---

Original:

You are correct that the password operation is separate. And the alternative of suppressing and sending your own email would work. Alternately, you can adjust the mail templates in the "Organization Related - Mail Template Management" you can update the email to indicate a password email will follow (and then directly send the password email) if that is a simplification for you.

It sounds like you have a use case that differs from others using the api (i.e. you are looking for an explicit password rather than to have an initial password allocated by the system). I would suggest you raise that as a request through the API support process: Probably just send an email to valence@desire2learn.com

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, the problem is the auto-generated password being null in the email. I don't mind what this password is as long as the system generates it and sends it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Verified that API based user creation follows the same rules as UI based creation:

The user is never sent a password, A help note from the UI for creating users reads:

> New users will receive an email from the system containing a secure
>   link enabling them to choose their new password. If the new user does
>   not have an email address, you can manually set their password if the
>   option is available to you.
>
> If you manually set the user's password, note the following:
>
> • The system cannot send passwords by email – you must contact the
>   user yourself
>
> • It is suggested that you force the user to reset their password

You may have a template in "Organization Related - Mail Template Management" that includes {Password} but that does not appear to be the correct macro. A valid template for new user messages should include  {PasswordResetLink} which is documented to be "Secure link to choose a new password."

Therefore, if you do not require a specific password, the recommended course of action is to update the new user template with {PasswordResetLink} and the workflow becomes:

1. App uses API to create user.
2. System sends message to user including
   link to set password.
3. User follows link and password is created.

If your API call or UI call does not follow that process on your site, it may be site context/config specific rather than a programmatic issue and I would consider contacting support.